# is it possible to calculate how many polygon can be rendered in unity 3d by using GPU information alone?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, gpu

Actually i am planning to buy a new laptop for game development and was wondering if is it possible to calculate which graphic card can rendered heavy geometry stuff without testing on actual hardware?

Is possible to calculate tentative number of polygon a graphic card render in unity3d?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that GPU render time heavily depends on how many vertices and pixels are being processed, the number of cycles necessary to run the shaders you need to run, the memory bandwidth of the GPU (due to the time it takes to receive instructions from the CPU), and the processing power of the GPU itself, as well as any limitations in how its shader cores can be used. It's too broad to be answered fully in one question here.

But, if you are able to render your game on graphics card A and you want an extremely rough estimate of render time on graphics card B, here's one option:

Take the render time on graphics card A and multiply it by A's FLOPS rate.  Then, divide by the FLOPS rate of B. The result is an extremely rough estimate of the render time on graphics card B. This estimate will only get less accurate the more differences there are between the scales/architectures of A and B.

The most accurate way to calculate max/min/average frame render speed is to experiment with the hardware in question.

Comment: a mayor factor at play here is shader complexity, vertex count is not that much of a limit these days